# UIAlertController Giving error? Please Give the code for UIAlertController with Array of Strings As Buttons in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

This is my code:
Please Check whether anything went Wrong?  Please give me the code for UIActionsheet (UIAlertController) with array in swift

```
let alertA = UIAlertController(title: "PlayLists", message: "Select From PlayLists Below", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style:  .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

})

let playListModel = PlayListModel.sharedInstance
plLists = playListModel.getPlayListNames()

for(var i = 0; i < plLists.count; i++){

    alertA.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: plLists.objectAtIndex(i) as? String, style: .Default, handler: {
    action in

        NSLog("%@",String(i))

    }))
}

alertA.addAction(action)
self.presentViewController(alertA, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In this code if I have 3 playlists the actionsheet shows three playlists along with cancel button. When I click the first button it will print value 4(where i stopped incrementing). Why is it printing this? It should print `i` value with 1, right? What's the problem? Is the Action inside the For Loop is Correct?

Comment: Looks like you have your languages mixed up? Why are you using NSLog function in your swift code. Try using the print statement instead.

Comment: @TheAppMentor NSLog has not been deprecated, it works ok with Swift. :) Although I also prefer using `print`, there's no problem using NSLog.

Comment: @TheAppMentor and Eric D..  Its ok but it should print 1 not 4... Why is it printing 4 instead of 1

Comment: It's an issue of scope, as explained here: http://moonbase.rydia.net/mental/blog/programming/the-biggest-mistake-everyone-makes-with-closures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I going to explain you why this happen, you can see if you touch any of your buttons always the output result of the call of `NSLog("%@",String(i))` is `plLists.count - 1`, this is because you're trying to set always the index of the `for` statement inside the closure of the actions you're adding. The variable is outside the scope of the closure.

The main problem is that always the reference retained inside the closure in your case is the last index of the array, because as you said is increased and finally when it finish is assigned the value.

Nevertheless, you can take an approach for the `title` property in the `action`, like in the following way:

```
func presentAction() {

    let alertA = UIAlertController(title: "PlayLists", message: "Select From PlayLists Below", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style:  .Default, handler: nil)

    let plLists = ["List1", "List2", "List3", "List4"]
    for(var i = 0; i < plLists.count; i++) {
        alertA.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: plLists[i], style: .Default, handler: self.handlerForAction)) 
    }

    alertA.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alertA, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func handlerForAction(action: UIAlertAction) {
    print(action.title!)
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why is it happening that way, So I Found out the Answer as an Alternative:

Using for loop in different way:

```
for titled in plLists{
 alertA.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: titled, style: .Default, handler: {
    action in

        NSLog(titled)

    }))
}
}
```

getting the correct output now, thanks for patience...